# Trying to use CocoaPods "WeScan" and I keep getting "No Such Module 'WeScan' " error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I keep getting this error while following these instructions to use WeScan. (https://schiavo.me/2019/scanning-documents-old/)

A few things that I have tried.

- Made sure its added in frameworks
- Added "%(SRCROOT)/Pods/" to my Header Search Paths
- Run `pod install` with the according Podfile (see code below)
- Used the .xcworkspace file

Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '12.4'

use_frameworks!

target 'ScannerApp' do
    pod 'WeScan', '~> 1.0.0'
end
```

Even when I downloaded the example git project (https://github.com/justJS/blog-example-code/tree/master/2019-02-24-ScanningDocumentsOld) I still get the same error. Is it my CocoaPods maybe?

edit:
I also get a black screen when I am in Main.storyboard. That is also something new?

Comment: change your platform :ios, '12.1' in your podfile

Comment: Didn't make a difference. I even created a new project and tried it.

Comment: have you tried clean build folder, closing xcode and tried again with build to get reconized pod

Comment: I tried cleaning it then deleting all related files and running `pod install` again. Peculiar that the same project doesn't work either. Shouldn't it work?

Comment: Try building after installing.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien would that just be `pod install`? EDIT: Sorry bad question. How would I build?

Comment: What is your xcode version and swift version in your project?

Comment: xcode 10.3 and swift 5 @AntonRodzik

Comment: try to remove line with platform from podfile and remove version from line with pod name and call pod install again.

Comment: Solved. By restarting my laptop -___-

Comment: Classic Xcode bug, if closing doesn't work, restarting does.